# Error while installing Sitecore package

Tags: sitecore-client

I was installing a package and got this error.

> The item name "Item1" is already defined on this level.

Is something wrong with my package creation?, How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the package creation it is due to default configuration, You need to change the setting name `AllowDuplicateItemNamesOnSameLevel` in `Sitecore.config` file under `App_Config` folder. Default it is false to restrict the duplication.

> < setting name="AllowDuplicateItemNamesOnSameLevel" value="false"/>

Just changed the setting to `true` and try the package installation.

You need to use the patch file to update the value as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
     <setting name="AllowDuplicateItemNamesOnSameLevel">
      <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
    </setting>  
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Would be wise to consider fixing the duplicate names rather than changing any setting to allow this behavior. You could introduce long term issues allowing duplicate names.